# Enumerable Route Params in angular2/4

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

Can we strict dynamic route parameters to accept only our predefined values.
Suppose I have the following route:

```
  {
    path: ":searchType",
    loadChildren: 'app/website/search.module#SearchModule'
  },
```

Now what I want to do is to define an array of values that `:searchType` can has. 
Is their a way to has something like this: `/:searchType(a|b|c|d|e)`

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? That one cannot access e.g. route `z`?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend your route with [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) / [CanActivateChild](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild) / [CanLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) guard or any combination of them (it all depends on your use cases).

```
{
  path: ":searchType",
  canActivate: ['enumerableParamsOnly'],
  canLoad: ['enumerableParamsOnly'],
  loadChildren: 'app/website/search.module#SearchModule'
},
```

and in the providers implement the desired behavior:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'enumerableParamsOnly',
    useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => ['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(route.params['searchType'])
  }
]
```

(or of course you can create a "normal" guard as a service).

Then, if you also want to display some page if somebody still comes to page outside of enumerable values range you can add a simple redirect. In this case you would need to implement a real guard because you would need to inject the router:

```
{
  path: ":searchType",
  canActivate: [EnumerableParamsOnlyGuard],
  canLoad: [EnumerableParamsOnlyGuard],
  loadChildren: 'app/website/search.module#SearchModule'
},
```

and the guard:

```
class EnumerableParamsOnlyGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.canLoad(route);
  }

  canLoad(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-enumerable-param');

    return ['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(route.params['searchType']);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this solution in my previous project.

```
const routes:Routes = [
{path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
{matcher: customUrlMatcher, loadChildren: path}
]

function customUrlMatcher(url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route){
 if(url.length){
   const[part1] = url;
   //you can match url here
   if(part1.path =='a')){
        let consumedUrl: UrlSegment[] = [];
        consumedUrl.push(url[0]);
     return{
        consumed: consumedUrl
   }
 }
}
```

ref: https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

Also, I have created a sample project on stackbliz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l13udh?file=app%2Fdummy.component.ts

Hopefully, This helps you.